# Image not showing on report viewer but link opens on design mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting

I'm trying to add ANY image from local disk into a report viewer with no luck.
First I've dragged the Image control to the report, i've set the Value property to all kinds of paths. Ex.: `="file://C:/Desert.jpg"`, `="file:\\\C:\Desert.jpg"`, etc.
On Design Mode, I `Ctrl + Click` on the link and visual studio is able to find the image.
When i run the project, i get the **x** error on the form which displays the report with the image.
If I try to set the value to a http link located on my local server, the image displays correctly. I have set the `EnableExternalImages` property to true.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to make the image embeded in your report

To do this, you have to:

1. Add an Image control in your RDLC
2. Be sure that the image source is set to `Embedded`
3. Click on `Import` and browse to your image

At this point, you should see the image also in the preview. To be more safer, in the design click on the image box, in the properties box search for `MIMEType` and select `image/jpg`

Now try to render your report. (if you want follow this way you can refer [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/22/adding-an-expression-based-image-in-a-client-report-definition-file-rdlc.aspx))

This solution is, ofc, not suitable if you have to create the same report with different logos: I found [this blog](http://hintdesk.com/c-excel-image-pdf-report-with-rdlc-in-masterdetails-and-multicolumn/) that explain how to create a `ReportParameter` in which store your dynamic path for the logo (paragraph `4.`)

And [here there is another example](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/160037/How-to-Pass-Image-in-Microsoft-Report) for external image. Note that he use `file:///` (three slash)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it works, but i have to dynamically load a path saved on database!

Comment: just follow the second link in my post! The one in which I mention `ReportParameter`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the image source needs to be relative to the report.

See: [Source Element (RDL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms152863%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

> Value contains a constant or an expression that evaluates to a relative path to the image on the report server.

Try placing the image in the same folder as the executable and putting just the file name of the image in the source property.

EDIT: to clarify, set `Source` to "External" and `Value` to "Desert.jpg".

Comment: I've tried your solution but it didn't work. I'm working with rdlc reports on visual studio (c#)

Comment: To illustrate what is happening I've took 2 screenshots: Design Mode OK: http://imageshack.us/f/837/designmode.jpg/
And Running the project: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/254/runningproject.jpg/

Comment: I use RDL reporting like you do, and I reference these files by simply having them in the same folder as the executable and putting the name in the value (as I posted in the answer). Your screenshot still shows you using a file url. Place a copy of the image in your Bin/Debug folder and just use the filename.

Comment: @Codesleuth if you do that you will limit the portability and reusability of your report. You always have to bring the image in the same folder of the executable and you can't reuse the report for more then one company (ofc, in case that the image is the logo of the company)

Comment: The end result would be to have this referenced by a report parameter - I wasn't suggesting leaving it like this, more like getting to the bottom of the problem first.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't catch that!

Comment: Just want to note that I do prefer your solution. Embedding the image is much more neat and manageable. If the OP would like it, I can post a method I wrote many years ago that generates a `ReportParameter` containing an `Image` that is sized and scaled to the report image placeholder, allowing images to be loaded from any file at runtime and inserted into the report. Probably not necessary unless requirements state that the image can change.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, what I was trying to do was to load an image on the reportviewer from a path saved on database. I was unable to do that following the tutorials on the internet. I tried Crystal Reports and it loaded the image from the path. So I think I'll stay with this solution, but seriously, it really looks like a bug on Visual Studio 2010, because as I said, I am able to see the image from the URL (file:// or file:///) link on Design Mode, but it does't show on the form with the report.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I also searched about the permissions for the unattended execution account or something like that, but I guess it doesn't applies on Windows Forms.